# Text box in gridview not auto post back

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox

My `gridview` missing previous data when post back. Here is the scenario, when I detect insufficient stock from `gvFinalised` gridview, I get the category, then I get the product with highest stock and display in `gvSuggested` gridview.

But let's say in my `gvFinalised`, there are three product with three different categories is insufficient, let's say they are Noodles, Canned Food and Beverages. It was supposed to display three different products with highest stock each from different categories in `gvSuggested`.

However, my problem now is, it just display the last items. For example, in this scenario, Beverages. The data before Beverages just get wiped out.

Here is the code on how I detect **insufficient stock**:

```
protected void tbQuantity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tempList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    distSPUItemList = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    bool valid = true;
    string quantityStr = "", prodID = "";
    int packagesNeeded = 0, totalUnit = 0, quantity = 0;

    //Get the total packages needed for this distribution
    packagesNeeded = prodPackBLL.getPackagesNeededByDistributionID(distributionID);

    foreach (GridViewRow gr in gvFinalised.Rows)
    {
        //Clear label error message
        Label lblCheckAmount = gr.FindControl("lblCheckAmount") as Label;
        lblCheckAmount.Text = "";

        //Get the product variant ID which set as DataKeyNames and product quantity from selected row index
        prodID = gvFinalised.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

        var tbQuantity = gr.FindControl("tbQuantity") as TextBox;
        if (tbQuantity != null)
        {
            //Check if the input is numeric
            quantityStr = tbQuantity.Text;
            if (!int.TryParse(quantityStr, out quantity))
            {
                lblCheckAmount.Text = "Non-numeric input!";
                TextBox tb = (TextBox)gr.FindControl("tbQuantity") as TextBox;
            }
            else
            {
                //Add both objects into Dictionary
                tempList.Add(prodID, quantityStr);
            }
        }
    }

    //Portion to check the storage level for each products stored in tempList
    //Loop thru tempList. key as prod variant ID, tempList.Keys as quantity
    foreach (string key in tempList.Keys)
    {
        //Get total unit of each products
        totalUnit = prodPackBLL.getTotalProductUnit(key);
        valid = true;

        //Check if unitQuantity exceed storage level
        if (((Convert.ToInt32(tempList[key])) * packagesNeeded) > totalUnit)
        {
            //Get the label control in gridview
            foreach (GridViewRow gr in gvFinalised.Rows)
            {
                if (key == gvFinalised.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString())
                {
                    //Change the color of textBox and display the insufficient message
                    valid = false;
                    //Automatically uncheck the checkBox if invalid
                    TextBox tb = (TextBox)gr.FindControl("tbQuantity") as TextBox;
                    Label lblCheckAmount = gr.FindControl("lblCheckAmount") as Label;
                    lblCheckAmount.Text = "Insufficient stock!";

                    //Here is the place where I collect the data and display in gvSuggested
                    getSuggested(key);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (totalUnit - ((Convert.ToInt32(tempList[key])) * packagesNeeded) == 0)
            {

                foreach (GridViewRow gr in gvFinalised.Rows)
                {
                    if (key == gvFinalised.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString())
                    {
                        valid = true;
                        Label lblCheckAmount = gr.FindControl("lblCheckAmount") as Label;
                        lblCheckAmount.Attributes["style"] = "color:#ffb848";
                        lblCheckAmount.Text = "Stock becomes 0!";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Portion to check for valid products to be inserted into distSPUItemList
        if (valid)
        {
            //Set the textBox color
            foreach (GridViewRow gr in gvFinalised.Rows)
            {
                if (key == gvFinalised.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString())
                {
                    TextBox tb = (TextBox)gr.FindControl("tbQuantity") as TextBox;
                }
            }
            //Validated items store into another list to perform Sql statement when button on click
            distSPUItemList.Add(key, (Convert.ToInt32(tempList[key]) * packagesNeeded));
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the `getSuggested()` method to populate my `gvSuggeted`:

```
protected void getSuggested(string prodVariantID)
{
    string categoryName = prodPackBLL.getCategoryByProdVariantID(prodVariantID);

    //Get the list of substitute product with highest storage level  sorted in descending order
    List<ProductPacking> prodSubstitute = new List<ProductPacking>();
    List<string> lstCategory = new List<string>();
    List<string> prodIDList = new List<string>();
    List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems> distSPUItem = new List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems>();

    distSPUItem = this.SuggestedItems;

    //Find list of substitute with highest stock level and replace the product
    prodSubstitute = prodPackBLL.getProductIDWithHighestStock(categoryName);

    for (int count = 0; count < prodSubstitute.Count; count++)
    {
        //To prevent duplication of same product and select those catories which are in current category and counting them and taking them if there are less than 1 occurrences
        if (!prodIDList.Contains(prodSubstitute[count].id) && !(lstCategory.Where(x => x.Equals(categoryName)).Select(x => x).Count() >= 2))
        {
            prodIDList.Add(prodSubstitute[count].id);
            lstCategory.Add(categoryName);
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < prodIDList.Count; j++)
    {
        //Get the detail of the product added into prodList and add it into distSPUItem List
        distSPUItem.Add(packBLL.getSPUItemDetailByID(prodIDList[j]));
    }

    gvSuggested.DataSource = distSPUItem;
    gvSuggested.DataBind();

    this.SuggestedItems = distSPUItem;
}

private List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems> SuggestedItems
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["SuggestedItems"] == null)
        {
            return new List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems>();
        }
        else
        {
            return (List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems>)ViewState["SuggestedItems"];
        }
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["SuggestedItems"] = value;
    }
}
```

I used a `viewState` to store the data when postback. However, it does not work. This line in **gvSuggested**:

```
this.SuggestedItems = distSPUItem;
```

causing my textbox in gridView not auto post back. If I removed it, the error above appear again. Any guides? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anybody know why? Is it because of the viewState problem or my logic problem?

Comment: Did you put `[Serializable]` attribute to `DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems` class?

Comment: @afzalulh It works. But why do I need to add [Serializable] in front of the class?

Comment: When you save List<T> in ViewState, you need to serializ them. See [Why Viewstate can contain only serializable object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841060/why-viewstate-can-contain-only-serializable-object). I wonder why you are not getting any error! I had an experience before, when I forgot to mark my class as Serializable, only one element was saved from the list!

Comment: I believe your question deserves an upvote! Because of the complex scenario, this question did not get enough attention.

Comment: Okay thanks alot. It's really weird cause my other portion which using view state works without putting the [Serilizable].

Answer (score 0):

Please enable tbQuantity text box  EnableAutoPostBack = True