# ViewState Throws System.Web.HttpUnhandledException When Is Initialized

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, viewstate

When I try to initialize ViewState key with value of type Group class it throws the following exception:

exception: **Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.Error serializing value 'MMS.Classes.DBEntities.Group' of type 'MMS.Cl.Entities.Group.'**

code:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Controls();
        }

        private void Controls()
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                ViewState["Group"] = new Group();
                ViewState["Group"] = new List<string>(); // if I use this line instead the above it works works
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is `Group` serializable?

Comment: What do you mean ? Group is a class which I created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think simply marking your `Group` class as `serializable` would make your code work, as the `ViewState` needs the class to be `serializable` to store it. For details about serialization you can visit this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx). Add `[Serializable]` attribute to your class as following:

```
[Serializable]
public class Group
{
//properties
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Now it works fine. What [Serializable] did for this class to make it work?

Comment: The answer to your question lies in understanding what serialization does. A serializable object can be transformed to any stream of data. Complex/Unmanaged objects/components can not be stored in ViewState. So ViewState need to know before hand that the Class that is being attempted to store is Serializable or not, marking class Serializable does that.

Answer (score 2):

since the result of storing items in ViewState is that those are stored in string on page (to maintain state between multiple requests), they need to be **serializable**, on the other hand **Session** is in memory storage (if you're using InProc mode, which is default, otherwise this doesn't apply), so objects don't need to be **serializable**.

**Refer to this for more details:**

[Why Viewstate can contain only serializable object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841060/why-viewstate-can-contain-only-serializable-object)

**Updated:**

You can find more information about Serialization here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx

**Hope this helps**
.

Comment: Nice point (voted one up) if you are planning to use the class across multiple pages then you can store it in session, but if its page specific usage then you should continue to use the ViewState by simply marking your class Serializable (that has no side affects :) ).